# Pass object that contains objects to Activity via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have an Object that I need to pass via the Intent to another Activity via the onclick method.

I was following this answer here [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) 
Which works fine however my Object has within it an Array of objects.

How do I pass this object with its Array of Objects?

Below are the classes before using Parcelable

List (the object to be passed)

```
public class List  {

    private String Name;
    private ArrayList<ListItem> items;

    public List(){
        items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    }

    public void addItem(String title, String d, String s, int p){
        ListItem i = new ListItem();
        i.setDecription(d);
        i.setPrice(p);
        i.setSite(s);
        i.setTitle(title);
        items.add(i);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<ListItem> getList(){
        return items;
    }
}
```

ListItem

```
public class ListItem {

    private String  title;
    private String  decription;
    private String  site;
    private int     price;


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setDecription(String d){
        this.decription = d;
    }
    public void setSite(String s){
        this.site = s;
    }
    public void setPrice(int i){
        this.price = i;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getDecription(){
        return decription;
    }
    public String getSite(){
        return site;
    }
    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
}
```

So how would I use Parcelable on List to send the ArrayList as well.

THank you and if you need any more info please ask!

Comment: You shouldn't use List as your own type. It's a java standard library interface.

Comment: Thousands of answers for this if you google it. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable

Comment: @VM good point shall rename, also could not find anything own parcleing an array list of custom objects

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I had seen this but he only has normal data types within their object

Comment: @ZacPowell its the same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass around data that shouldn't normally be passed around. A list is an ideal candidate for an SQLite Database. Try that or another way to persist data in android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If you insist on using Parcelable:
[How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable)

Also don't use List as your own type, it's standard JAVA.

Comment: Very good point about using a SQL I shall look into doing this instead thank you